# In selenium ruby tests can I combine the setup and teardown methods into one location for all my tests?

Tags: ruby, selenium

In my ruby Selenium Tests there is a lot of the same code in every test. How can I best share code between tests?  For example my setup and teardown methods are the same in every file, how can I remove them from every file into one shared file or is that even possible?

```
def setup
    @verification_errors = []
    @selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
    :host => "#$sell_server",
    :port => 4444,
    :browser => "#$browser",
    :url => "http://#$network.#$host:2086/",
    :timeout_in_second => 60

    @selenium.start_new_browser_session
end

def teardown
    @selenium.close_current_browser_session
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
end
```

I've tried putting setup in a shared module and a required file but both present different problems with inheritance of the other methods that need access to the @selenium object that is started.  What would be a good design if there is one for sharing the code?

Comment: I had some success with making a class SharedTest < Test::Unit::TestCase which includes setup / teardown / test_default methods and then having my class TestName < SharedTest.  However running the test opens and closes a browser, then opens another one and runs my test successfully and closes, then opens and closes a third browser and reports 3 tests passing. Not sure of myself what the proper way of doing this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test unit framework - it seems to work to create a SharedTest class to inherit from Test::Unit::Testcase with setup and teadown methods. Then just subclass the test files SharedTest.  The only negative consequence I've found is I had to add a test_default method that does nothing in SharedTest to get it to work.  If I name my test method test_default that overides it and seems ok, but not very descriptive...

sharedtest.rb

```
class SharedTest < Test::Unit::Testcase
  def setup
    @verification_errors = []
    @selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
    :host => "#$sell_server",
    :port => 4444,
    :browser => "#$browser",
    :url => "http://#$network.#$host:2086/",
    :timeout_in_second => 60

    @selenium.start_new_browser_session
 end

 def teardown
    @selenium.close_current_browser_session
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
 end

 def test_default
   #puts self
 end
end
```

T01_testcasename.rb

```
 class Test_01_whatever < SharedTest
   def test_default
      #test code
   end
```

I'm still open to better solutions but this seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what test framework you're using, but in rspec you could place it into your spec_helper file and just do a before(:each) / after(:each).  I'd check the callback documentation for your framework of choice.

Comment: I'm using the test unit framework.  I think its a generic inheritance lack of understanding on my part.  I tried putting in a SharedTest class that subclasses from Test::Unit::TestCase which includes setup / teardown and then having my test subclass SharedTest.  It fails with "No tests were specified." error.  Splitting up the setup/teardown from the test_ methods seems to break.